# How to use "has_term" correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Im working with the single product page and I need to have a different image (depending on the category) after the add to cart button.

I tried this code but it doesn't show me the image that I need

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_button' );
function content_after_button() {
if (has_term( 'Categoria', 'Accesorios' ) ) {
echo 'https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/iconos2.jpg';
}
```

I think im using has_term in the wrong way.

What im trying to accomplish is: 
I have a parent category that is "Accesorios" and inside that I have other child categories like "Billeteras". For each one of this child categories it has to show a diferent image.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is issue with your `has_term` checking. If you check has_term [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), you can find it takes first parameter as category term and second parameter as taxonomy.
Add secondly you are just echo image url that is not going to display image.
So, do as follows -

```
add_action ( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'content_after_button' );
function content_after_button() {
    // do check with has_term( $term = '', $taxonomy = '', $post = null )
    if( has_term( 'Accesorios', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<img src="https://prueba.soygorrion.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/iconos2.jpg" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,your answer clear mi mind. What about the products that have twi categories? Like "accesorios" and "billeteras" (because accesories is the parent) Thank you again im new at coding

Comment: You can use OR condition in if statement like `if ( has_term( 'cat_1', 'product_cat' ) || has_term( 'cat_2', 'product_cat' ) ) {}` or you can pass directly array as term like `if ( has_term( array('cat_1', 'cat_2), 'product_cat' ) ) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the problem is with has_term function. If you can get the product ID inside add to cart, then you can use this code to get categories and check them:

```
$categories = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
if(in_array("Accesorios", $categories))
{
    echo "bla bla";
}
```

I have tested this code for another purpose, it works fine. I hope this will help. Please inform me when you test it and if you face any errors update your question with your new code.